# Maximum and minimum value of $\frac{8x - 3y}{\sqrt{4x^2+y^2}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For real numbers $\,x, y\neq 0\,$ consider
$$\frac{8x - 3y}{\sqrt{4x^2+y^2}}\,.$$
How to find the maximum and minimum value?

I've already got the maximum by using the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality
$$\big[(2x)^2 + y^2\big]\big[4^2 + (-3)^2\big] \geq (8x - 3y)^2\\[3ex]
25 \geq \frac{(8x - 3y)^2}{(2x)^2 + y^2}\\[4ex]
5 \geq \frac{8x - 3y}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 + y^2}}$$

But I cannot get the minimum value.

Comment: If $(x,y)=(0,1)$, your expression evaluates to $-3$, which is less than $5$. So your minimum is wrong. (Also, [please use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)!)

Comment: Sorry , I lost another constraint.
$x , y$ are non-zero real number

Comment: Isn't Cauchy Schwarz valid only for non-negative numbers?

Comment: You have Cauchy-Schwarz backwards! Your $\le$ should be $\ge$.

Comment: @TonyK thank you, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there: Note that by Cauchy-Schwarz you  did
$$25 \geq \frac{(8x - 3y)^2}{(2x)^2 + y^2}\,.$$
Thus
$$\left|\frac{8x-3y}{\sqrt{4x^2+y^2}}\right|\le 5\tag {*}\\[5ex]
\implies -5\le \frac{8x-3y}{\sqrt{4x^2+y^2}}\le 5$$
The important part was in step (*). The modulus was crucial as $8x-3y$ could be negative too.

Comment: Sir Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore, bear with me please for permitting myself to accomplish some obvious mod's.

Comment: @Hanno LOL ,didnt know the mathjax and BTW After reading  dwathly hallows for over 5 times still havent taken time to memeorise Dumbledores full name

Comment: Thanks for editing

Answer (score 3):

Let $r > 0$ and $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$, and $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = 2r \sin \theta$, so that $$4x^2 + y^2 = 4r^2,$$ hence $$\begin{align}f(x,y) &= \frac{8x-3y}{\sqrt{4x^2 + y^2}} \\ &= \frac{8r \cos \theta - 6r \sin \theta}{2r} \\ &= 4 \cos \theta - 3 \sin \theta \\
&= 5 \left(\frac{4}{5} \cos \theta - \frac{3}{5} \sin \theta \right) \\
&= 5 \left( \sin \psi \cos \theta - \cos \psi \sin \theta \right) \quad \quad \psi = \arcsin \frac{4}{5} \\
&= 5 \sin(\theta - \psi).
\end{align}$$  Now we can see this function depends only on the choice of angle $\theta$.  This is obviously maximized when $\theta = \psi + \pi/2$ and the maximum attained is $5$.

This also happens to get us the minimum for free, which occurs when $\theta = \psi + \frac{3\pi}{2},$ and the minimum is $-5$.